# Uploading MANY files at once with Flask-Dropzone

Tags: python, flask, dropzone

I'm trying to upload many small (<200KB) files to my database at once (200 files) using Flask-Dropzone inside a form. Currently, I am able to submit 50 or so files no problem along with the other form fields that go along with them in a separate table. My files table points to the related table with the extra form info. Each set of files uploaded are then stored as a LargeBinary blob in a SQLite database. What's my best bet for having my site handle all 200 files in a single, or very few, post requests? Here are my current relevant views, routes, and dropzone config settings.

View (upload.html)

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
{% extends "user_layout.html" %}
{% else %}
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% endif %}
{% block content %}

<div class="header-blue">
    <div class="container hero">
        <div class="content-section-upload">
            <fieldset class="form-group">   
                <div class="font_headers">
                    <h2 > Drag or Drop DICOM   </h2>
                </div>                  
                <form action="{{ url_for('handle_form') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    <label for="Study Name">Study Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="Study Name" name="Study Name"/><br>
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" id="description" name="description"/><br>
                    {{ dropzone.create() }}
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit and Upload">
                </form>
                {{ dropzone.load_js() }}
                {{ dropzone.config() }}
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Routes (routes.py)

```
@app.route("/upload",  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    return render_template('upload.html')


@app.route("/dropzone_handler",  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dropzone_handler():
    files_list = []
    for key, f in request.files.items():
        if key.startswith('file'):
            files_list.append(f)
    file_count = len(files_list)
    binary_files = [file.read() for file in files_list] # list of bytes objects
    binary_blob = pickle.dumps(binary_files) # binary blob

    ### generate thumbnail
    data = pickle.loads(binary_blob) 
    dicom_list = []
    for byte_file in data: # list of all dicom files in binary
        raw = DicomBytesIO(byte_file)
        dicom_list.append(dcmread(raw))

    # find median dicom file to generate thumbnail
    median_i = len(dicom_list)//2
    median_dicom = dicom_list[median_i]

    tn = graphing([median_dicom])

    size = (300, 300)
    tn.thumbnail(size)

    # convert thumbnail to bytes

    def imgToBytes(img):
        img_bytes = BytesIO()
        img.save(img_bytes, format='PNG')
        img_bytes = img_bytes.getvalue()

        return img_bytes

    tn_bytes = imgToBytes(tn)

    filename = "file name"

    global session_id
    ## database upload
    batch = Dicom( 
    user_id=current_user.id,
    dicom_stack = binary_blob, 
    thumbnail = tn_bytes,
    file_count= file_count,
    session_id=str(session_id))
    db.session.add(batch) 
    db.session.commit()
    return ''


@app.route('/form', methods=['POST'])
def handle_form():
    study_name = request.form.get('Study Name')
    description = request.form.get('description')
    global session_id
    formData = DicomFormData( 
        study_name=study_name,
        description=description,
        session_id=str(session_id))
    db.session.add(formData) 
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('browser'))

@app.before_request
def before_request_func(): 
    webpages = ['job','account', 'upload', 'home', 'index', 'doc', 'logout', 'browser']
    if current_user.is_authenticated and request.endpoint =='upload':
        # upload id
        global session_id
        session_id = request_id()
        print('SESSION_ID:', session_id)
    if current_user.is_authenticated and request.endpoint in webpages:
        # temp file management
        temp_dir = os.getcwd() + "\\vessel_app\\static\\media\\" 
        temp_user_dir = "user_" + str(current_user.id)
        current_user_dir = temp_dir + temp_user_dir
        state = os.path.isdir(current_user_dir)

        if state == True:
            shutil.rmtree(current_user_dir)
        elif state == False:
            return
```

config.py

```
...

# Flask-Dropzone config:
    DROPZONE_ALLOWED_FILE_CUSTOM= True
    DROPZONE_ALLOWED_FILE_TYPE='image/*, .dcm'
    DROPZONE_MAX_FILE_SIZE=3
    DROPZONE_MAX_FILES=30
    DROPZONE_UPLOAD_MULTIPLE=True
    DROPZONE_IN_FORM=True
    DROPZONE_UPLOAD_ON_CLICK=True
    DROPZONE_UPLOAD_ACTION='dropzone_handler'  # URL or endpoint
    DROPZONE_UPLOAD_BTN_ID='submit'
```

Comment: You say 50 files work, but what is the error/problem that you get when trying 200?

Comment: With 200 files, the program gets stuck in a loop submitting the form over and over again forever. Its like flask and/or dropzone doesn't know how to handle that many files so it freaks out and tries to make a POST request to '/form' over and over again.